# Slack respond to dialog submission with another dialog

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is there any way in the Slack API to have the submission button of a dialog open a new dialog or edit the current one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly. You can use the `response_url` attached to the dialog submission sent to your server to then post a follow up ephemeral message to the user, containing a button to continue to the next dialog. Once clicked, you'll receive another `trigger_id` which you can send to `dialog.open` and start another dialog.

More information on triggers and where to find them can be found [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/triggers).

Comment: Does this mean a `trigger_id` can only be used once?

Comment: Correct, it's single use with a limited time window.

Comment: How do you obtain the trigger_id?  Can you get it from a simple slash command?

Comment: A `trigger_id` is attached to slash command invocations, message button or menu selections, action invocations, and dialog submissions. In all cases, they must be part of a Slack app -- legacy custom integration slash commands will not participate.

Comment: I don't get any `response_url` from my modal (before called dialog)